# URI segment does not get returned when using querystrings

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, uri, codeigniter-3

I'm trying to paginate the search results returned by the query. I have the following URL:

```
blog/search?query=post/5
```

Where I am trying to get the value of `$start=5` from the URL using:

```
$start = $this->uri->segment(3);
```

It is not returning anything.

Where removing `?query=post`, i.e, `blog/search/5` works fine. But I want to keep the query parameter and read the value.

Comment: remove this `?query=post` and follow link : https://www.formget.com/codeigniter-uri-segment/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because of the `?` character in the URI. CodeIgniter URI parser (and any other standard URI parser) does not recognize what you have in mind. After the `?` character, it's all query string, not URI segments. See the output of PHP's [`parse_url()`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php):

```
parse_url('blog/search?query=post/5')
[
    "path" => "blog/search",
    "query" => "query=post/5",
]
```

See? The first segment is `blog`, the second is `search` and the rest is the querystring.

You need to change your URI design in an standard way. For example:

```
blog/search/5?query=post
```

So that the call to `$this->uri->segment(3)` will return what you have in mind.

Speaking of CodeIgniter pagination library, see `reuse_query_string` and `page_query_string` configs in the [documentation](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html).

Comment: thank you for sharing the knowledge. but i am using CI pagination library where i am defining $config['base_url'] = base_url().'blog/search?query=' . urlencode($query); . Is there anyway to tell CI pagination library to make the "base_url" like this--> blog/search/5?query=post. Thank you again

Comment: See CodeIgniter's `reuse_query_string` config for its [pagination library](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/pagination.html). Or you can completely convert pagination params to querystring by setting `page_query_string` config to true. Read the docs.

Comment: Thanks a lot it works great now. I did $config['reuse_query_string'] = true;
  $config['base_url'] = base_url().'blog/search';

Comment: The same docs I scrolled in front of my eyes, in the search of result my mind was tired. Well Thank you..